# c++: How to i add an integer to a string

Tags: c++, string, integer, text-files, filenames

```
int value = rand() % 1000;

string filelocation = "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/textfile"

string textfile = ".txt";
```

How can I add these together and store it into another string variable

e.g.

```
string test = "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/textfile123.txt"
```

This way i will be able to create a unique named text file each time the code is run via:

```
outfile.open(test, std::ios::app);
```

ive tried:

```
outfile.open("C:/Users/admin/Documents/textfile" + value + ".txt", std::ios::app);
```

but i get the error `'+' : cannot add two pointers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a std::stringstream. Try something like this

```
int value = rand() % 1000;
string filelocation = "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/textfile"
string textfile = ".txt"; 

std::stringstream out;
out << filelocation << value << textfile;
outfile.open(out.str(), std::ios::app);
```

Comment: This compiles and runs but it only works the first time around, every time i try and run the code after the initial run, it doesnt generate a random file anymore, it just opens the initial text file made instead of generating a random text file.

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: @user3131101 you're appending to the file as you specified std::ios::app when you open it. Without seeing more code it's hard to say what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Convert to string the value with std::to_string() function.
You have to do `outfile.open("C:/Users/admin/Documents/textfile" + std::to_string(value) + ".txt", std::ios::app);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function snprintf or sprintf.If use the snprintf,you have to apply another string to save your "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/textfile".
eg:
sprintf():
sprintf(str,"c:\xxx\%d",%d);

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert `value` to a string before you use it as described.  Right now, you are trying to add a binary value to a string.  Look for `stringstream` to help you understand conversion from `int` to `string`.